# How do I get InputStream from AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm doing a homework about creating **EarthQuake Viewer** at Profession Android 2 Application Development. I got an error `Networkonmainthreadexception` . I changed my code with `AsyncTask` but it still appearing that error. [page 148 at http://docdro.id/1GgD2Pc]

```
public class refreshQuake extends AsyncTask<String/* Param */, InputStream /* Progress */, Boolean /* Result */> {
    Activity ctx;
    ListView earthquakeListView;
    ArrayAdapter<Quake> arrayAdapter;
    ArrayList<Quake> earthquakes = new ArrayList<Quake>();
    public refreshQuake(Activity ctx){
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            URLConnection connection;
            connection = url.openConnection();

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
            connection.setConnectTimeout(2000);
            int responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
            if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                int layoutID = android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
                earthquakes.clear();
                arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Quake>(ctx, layoutID, earthquakes);
                publishProgress(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
                return true;
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(InputStream... inputStream){
        super.onProgressUpdate(inputStream[0]);
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document dom = documentBuilder.parse(inputStream[0]);
            Element docEle = dom.getDocumentElement();
            NodeList nodeList = docEle.getElementsByTagName("entry");
            if(nodeList != null && nodeList.getLength() > 0){
                for(int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++){
                    Element entry = (Element) nodeList.item(i);
                    Element title = (Element) entry.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0);
                    Element g = (Element) entry.getElementsByTagName("georss:point").item(0);
                    Element when = (Element) entry.getElementsByTagName("updated").item(0);
                    Element link = (Element) entry.getElementsByTagName("link").item(0);

                    String details = title.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                    String hostname = "http://earthquake.usgs.gov";
                    String linkString = hostname + link.getAttribute("href");

                    String point = g.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                    String dt = when.getFirstChild().getNodeName();
                    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'");
                    Date qdate = new GregorianCalendar(0,0,0).getTime();
                    try{
                        qdate = simpleDateFormat.parse(dt);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    String[] location = point.split(" ");
                    Location l = new Location("dummyGPS");
                    l.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(location[0]));
                    l.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(location[1]));

                    String magnitudeString = details.split(" ")[1];
                    int end = magnitudeString.length()-1;
                    double magnitude = Double.parseDouble(magnitudeString.substring(0, end));

                    details = details.split(",")[1].trim();

                    Quake quake = new Quake(qdate, details, l, magnitude, linkString);
                    earthquakeListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                    addNewQuake(quake);

                }
            }

        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean inputStream) {
        super.onPostExecute(inputStream);

    }
    private void addNewQuake(Quake _quake){
        earthquakes.add(_quake);

        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

My input is `rQuake.execute(getString(http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/map/));`

Error`Networkonmainthreadexception` at line

```
Document dom = documentBuilder.parse(inputStream[0]);
```

How do I get `InputStream` ?

---

### Update 1

```
public class refreshQuake extends AsyncTask<String/* Param */, Quake /* Progress */, Boolean /* Result */> {
    Activity ctx;
    ListView earthquakeListView;
    ArrayAdapter<Quake> arrayAdapter;
    ArrayList<Quake> earthquakes = new ArrayList<Quake>();
    public refreshQuake(Activity ctx){
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            URLConnection connection;
            connection = url.openConnection();

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
            int responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
            if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                int layoutID = android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
                earthquakes.clear();
                arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Quake>(ctx, layoutID, earthquakes);
                DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document dom = documentBuilder.parse(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
                Element docEle = dom.getDocumentElement();
                NodeList nodeList = docEle.getElementsByTagName("entry");
                if(nodeList != null && nodeList.getLength() > 0){
                    for(int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++){
                        Element entry = (Element) nodeList.item(i);
                        Element title = (Element) entry.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0);
                        Element g = (Element) entry.getElementsByTagName("georss:point").item(0);
                        Element when = (Element) entry.getElementsByTagName("updated").item(0);
                        Element link = (Element) entry.getElementsByTagName("link").item(0);

                        String details = title.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                        String hostname = "http://earthquake.usgs.gov";
                        String linkString = hostname + link.getAttribute("href");

                        String point = g.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                        String dt = when.getFirstChild().getNodeName();
                        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'");
                        Date qdate = new GregorianCalendar(0,0,0).getTime();
                        try{
                            qdate = simpleDateFormat.parse(dt);
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        String[] location = point.split(" ");
                        Location l = new Location("dummyGPS");
                        l.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(location[0]));
                        l.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(location[1]));

                        String magnitudeString = details.split(" ")[1];
                        int end = magnitudeString.length()-1;
                        double magnitude = Double.parseDouble(magnitudeString.substring(0, end));

                        details = details.split(",")[1].trim();
                        Quake quake = new Quake(qdate, details, l, magnitude, linkString);
                        publishProgress(quake);
                return true;
            }}

                }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Quake... quake){

        super.onProgressUpdate(quake);
        System.out.println("test2");
        earthquakeListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        addNewQuake(quake[0]);


    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean inputStream) {
        super.onPostExecute(inputStream);

    }
 private void addNewQuake(Quake _quake){
        earthquakes.add(_quake);

        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Output is

```
02-26 22:07:01.997 20240-2079/com.begood.earthquake W/System.err: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: expected: /link read: head (position:END_TAG </head>@6:176 in java.io.InputStreamReader@b41220f0) 
02-26 22:07:01.997 20240-2079/com.begood.earthquake W/System.err:     at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:146)
02-26 22:07:01.997 20240-2079/com.begood.earthquake W/System.err:     at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:107)
02-26 22:07:01.997 20240-2079/com.begood.earthquake W/System.err:     at com.begood.earthquake.refreshQuake$override.doInBackground(refreshQuake.java:56)
02-26 22:07:01.997 20240-2079/com.begood.earthquake W/System.err:     at com.begood.earthquake.refreshQuake$override.access$dispatch(refreshQuake.java)
02-26 22:07:01.997 20240-2079/com.begood.earthquake W/System.err:     at com.begood.earthquake.refreshQuake.doInBackground(refreshQuake.java:0)
02-26 22:07:01.997 20240-2079/com.begood.earthquake W/System.err:     at com.begood.earthquake.refreshQuake.doInBackground(refreshQuake.java:32)
02-26 22:07:01.997 20240-2079/com.begood.earthquake W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-26 22:07:01.997 20240-2079/com.begood.earthquake W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
02-26 22:07:01.997 20240-2079/com.begood.earthquake W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-26 22:07:01.997 20240-2079/com.begood.earthquake W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-26 22:07:01.997 20240-2079/com.begood.earthquake W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
02-26 22:07:01.997 20240-2079/com.begood.earthquake W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
02-26 22:07:01.997 20240-2079/com.begood.earthquake W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Line 56 is `Document dom = documentBuilder.parse(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());`
Line 32 is `public class refreshQuake extends AsyncTask<String/* Param */, Quake /* Progress */, Boolean /* Result */>`

---

### Update 2

With new XML

```
<string name="quake_feed">
        http://earthquake.usgs.gov/realtime/product/origin/pr16057008/pr/1456491131155/product.xml
    </string>

02-26 22:36:05.964 20240-20258/com.begood.earthquake I/System.out: 200 200
02-26 22:36:21.715 5892-5892/com.begood.earthquake I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
02-26 22:36:22.554 5892-5892/com.begood.earthquake I/System.out: Debugger has connected
02-26 22:36:22.554 5892-5892/com.begood.earthquake I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
02-26 22:36:22.754 5892-5892/com.begood.earthquake I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
02-26 22:36:22.964 5892-5892/com.begood.earthquake I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
02-26 22:36:23.174 5892-5892/com.begood.earthquake I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
02-26 22:36:23.384 5892-5892/com.begood.earthquake I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
02-26 22:36:23.594 5892-5892/com.begood.earthquake I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
02-26 22:36:23.794 5892-5892/com.begood.earthquake I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
02-26 22:36:24.004 5892-5892/com.begood.earthquake I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
02-26 22:36:24.214 5892-5892/com.begood.earthquake I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
02-26 22:36:24.424 5892-5892/com.begood.earthquake I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
02-26 22:36:24.625 5892-5892/com.begood.earthquake I/System.out: debugger has settled (1325)
02-26 22:36:24.685 5892-5892/com.begood.earthquake I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getSystemService, referenced from method com.begood.earthquake.MainActivity.access$super
02-26 22:36:24.685 5892-5892/com.begood.earthquake W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 424: Landroid/content/Context;.getSystemService (Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
02-26 22:36:24.694 5892-5892/com.begood.earthquake I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.ContextWrapper.getSystemServiceName, referenced from method com.begood.earthquake.MainActivity.access$super
02-26 22:36:24.694 5892-5892/com.begood.earthquake W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 497: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.getSystemServiceName (Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. You can't use any networking `InputStream` in the main thread (where `onProgressUpdate` is run).

Parse the document in the worker thread (`doInBackground`) and pass only the result.

Comment: So I should edit my `AsyncTask<String/* Param */, Quake /* Progress */, Boolean /* Result */>` right/

Comment: @GiaVũ If `Quake` does not contain any views (which can be created only on main thread) then it should work

Comment: Updated question. Please take a look!

Comment: @GiaVũ It says the parsed document is not a valid XML. Are you trying to parse HTML with a XML parser?

Comment: You mean this `<string name="quake_feed"> http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/map/ </string>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using inputStream correctly, try this way:

```
  super.onProgressUpdate(inputStream);
...

    Document dom = documentBuilder.parse(inputStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

You error because you placed `documentBuilder.parse(inputStream);` to MainThread.The inputstream is from network,so this is same as you read something from network on MainThread,so such error exists.

So you should place it in your `doInBackground`,once you get data,pass it to `onProgressUpdate` or `onPostExecute`.

Comment: Updated my question. Please take a look at it!